# Qt c++ QPixmap check if its initialized

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

i try to check if QPixmap is initialized, when i try to check using :

```
QPixmap pix;

    if(pix.data_ptr())
    or
    if(pix != null)
```

where pix is member of QPixmap type .

all gives me :

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000000c.
```

how can i check in code if pix is null ?

Comment: What data type is `item`?

Comment: it is  general that in its constructor i set up dummy QPixmap object
my question is how to check QPixmap if it initialized or not

Comment: I think you need to provide a clearer description of what you're trying to do. @cartman told you how to check if a QPixmap is initialised, but it doesn't seem that that was really your question.  If the small amount of code you have given is causing a crash it's because item wasn't initialised.

Comment: forget the item , i want to check only if pix initialized 
i updated the question

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If you declare `pix` like that, you cannot compare it to null. `pix` just cannot be null (or uninitialized). Please show code that compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case when non-pointer QPixmap could be not initialized is when code like this is executed:

```
QPixmap getPixmap()
{
 // no return statement here
}

QPixmap pix = getPixmap();
// now pix is invalid but .isNull() will return false
```

I've had similar issues with no-initialized QStrings.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `isNull()` function,

```
if(!item->pix.isNull())
```

Comment: no , its only working if the QPixmap initialized  with object dummy object . but here i want to check if the QPixmap is initialized or not with this dummy object

Comment: Since your "pix" is not a pointer, it'll be always be initialized with the dummy object.

Comment: no its not , i have here case where somehow i dont know how 
its only get the deceleration without setting the dummy object.
but its doesn't matter . i want to check if its initialized

Comment: forget the item , i want to check only if pix initialized 
i updated the question

Comment: In which case this is the correct answer and you should accept it.